# Zoom alternatives

Tags: chat, productivity, video-conferencing

A friends organization has banned Zoom for security reasons.

For on-line courses they would like conferencing software that supports:

- breakout rooms
- hand raising
- doc sharing
- video presentations (interruptible)

Comment: Not sure about the doc-sharing part (but I guess there's an addon for that): take a look at [BigBlueButton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigBlueButton). I just had my first talk on that platform yesterday (as the presenter/speaker). Definitely can confirm the first two points working great, and saw an option for the last. Allows to share your screen (all, or single window), which was how I put up my presentations. Has a whiteboard to paint/write on, lets you upload presentations to use "inline". Focus on education, interacts with lots of things. FOSS (free, open-source). 130 people joined, np

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following things with [jitsi](https://jitsi.org/jitsi-meet/)

- Share your desktop, presentations, and more Invite users to a
  conference via a simple, custom URL
- Edit documents together using Etherpad
- Pick fun meeting URLs for every meeting
- Trade messages and emojis while you video conference, with integrated chat.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question, that organisation has stopped using Zoom for security reasons therefore I will recommend Microsoft Teams.

[Microsoft Teams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software) allows hand raising, file sharing and storage, collaborate live in real time to work on same document. It has recently integrated whiteboard and breakout room functions also. Both free and paid plans are available with special plans for academic institutions and non profit organisations.

The best part is that we can [take a demo](https://teamsdemo.office.com/) of Microsoft Teams without sign up.

[Google Classroom](https://edu.google.com/products/classroom/) along with [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com/) is also a good alternative. Although currently it does not provide many features compared to its competitors, being a browser based application, some features could be incorporated into it using the already availabe Chrome extensions for it.

Comment: You're suggesting that open source and free is less secure. Can you back that up, or remove that phrase?

Answer (score 1):

There are some alternative to Zoom:

- Google Hangouts (https://hangouts.google.com/)
- Google Meet (https://meet.google.com/). I prefer this one.
- Skype (https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/)
- Proficonf (https://proficonf.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Cisco Webex — Online Meetings and Video Conferencing](https://www.webex.co.in/)

Webex online meetings and presentations, webinars, town halls, hand raising,
doc sharing, online courses and training, and online presentations.